# Iterating over a ruby object in Javascript using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select2-rails

I am working on a rails app that is using the select 2 gem.  I have select 2 working but I need to be able to input the correct data into the data portion of the function, to do that I would like to iterate over an object called MagazineStation.  I have tried a bunch of different stuff but I can not get it to work.  So in the data portion of the function I would like to iterate over MagazineStation object using ruby, inputing the id and name.

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#e11").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a Station",
        allowClear: true,
        multiple: true,
        data: [{id: 0, text: 'story'},{id: 1, text: 'bug'},{id: 2, text: 'task'}]
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<input id="e11">
```

Comment: So you want to replace the `data: [...]` with `data: <%= someMagicFunction(MagazineStation) %>`?  If so, you'll have to show the ruby class def of MagazineStation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output ruby into your javascript with ERB such as this:

```
<%= MagazineStation.all.map { |ms| { id: ms.id, text: ms.name } }.to_json %>
```

The `.to_json` part is key to outputting an Array-looking string into your template (and in a javascript-friendly fashion).

But you do need to make sure you're putting this into your script within your page. So it may be easier to start by creating a regular select with e.g. a [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper and then turning that data into a select2 element on page load.

Comment: Thanks, Paul N. That does seem better since it puts quotes around the keys. Has the potential to avoid issues in javascript hash. So editing my answer to use `.to_json`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Iterate the Ruby object in .erb file.

```
data: [                
 <% @Magzinestation.each do |t|%>    
    {"<%=raw t[0] %>",<%=raw t[1]%>},
  <%end%>]
```

This script will replace the   data [] to data[ {data 1}, {data 2}...]

Comment: at least you should escape javascript output

Comment: yes...@paul N I totally forgot. I'll update this answer.